# MSMQ: Unable to retrieve some messages

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I encountered a problem yesterday with MSMQ and I would like to know the reason for it.

I have a server sending messages to a MSMQ, and a client consuming those messages. Yesterday the client stopped retrieving one type of message, yet was able to retrieve another type of message that was sent after. I've read some stuff regarding Poison messages, but this behavior doesn't fit in any of the described cases that I've seen, since if that was the case the client shouldn't be able to retrieve messages arriving after the poison message. The problem went away after I cleaned the message queue manually.

I also checked the svc log and there were no exceptions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you serializing your messages? Binary, XML, some other format?

Comment: No idea, I'm using this over WCF.

Comment: What were the symptoms in more detail? Did the messages stay in the queue and they were basically not processed? Or were they moved into the dead letter queue?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that another client application or service is contributing a message with "MessageFormatter" that you are not expecting?